# What's the correct type for a general-purpose match function for tagged unions?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement a `match` function that would work similar to Rust's [match keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/match.html), but adjusted for TypeScript's structural type system.

It's possible (but not ergonomic) to explicitly write the function's type for each unnamed tagged union that needs to be matched. Currently the best alternative seems to be switch-case, which have to be wrapped in `(()=>{})()` to work as expressions.

```js
// what type should this function have?
function match(value, cases) {
  return cases[value.tag](value);
}

// example 1
type Shape =
  | {tag: 'circle', radius: number}
  | {tag: 'textbox', text: string};

const shape: Shape = {tag: 'textbox', text: 'Hello world!'};

log(match(shape, {
  // both fields are required
  circle: ({radius}) => `A circle with radius ${radius}`,
  textbox: ({text}) => `A text box that says "${text}"`
})); // -> 'A text box that says "Hello world!"'

// example 2
const point = {tag: 'point', x: 1, y: 2} as const;

log(match(point, {
  // only one case is required
  point: ({x, y}) => `A point at (${x}, ${y})`
})); // -> 'A point at (1, 2)'
```

Some desired properties:

1. Should verify that each possible tag has a corresponding case function.
2. Should auto-complete tag names in the second argument based on the value's type.
3. Should not require explicit generic parameters.
4. **Update:** Should correctly infer the returned type as a union of all the possible types.

In case it's currently theoretically impossible to implement this, I'd like to know why and whether there's a work-in-progress language feature that will make this possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a combination of mapped types and conditionals (taking advantage of the builtin [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu)):

```js
type Cases<V extends {tag: string}, R> = {
    [K in V['tag']]: (v: Extract<V, {tag: K}>) => R
}
function match<V extends {tag: string}, R>(value: V, cases: Cases<V, R>): R {
  return (cases as any)[value.tag](value);
}
```

This signature will give an error for missing cases, infer the discriminated value type for the case (autocompletes in the playground only if the `=>` is typed first), and raise an error for missing cases when specified as a literal.

**Note**: it will infer a stronger type than `Shape` for your `shape` example because of the `const` assignment. In that case the `match` call will raise an error about the extra case `circle` but providing the types explicitly silences that. `match<Shape, string>(shape, {...})`

[Link to playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-G806XHZJlAlQBaPgKN0wtNYDMhbO5qB5qk0umM5lsvMKGZK7BLFbQABMyNRWbAvmYWbx8Uu09nUKwNDWnBANFHrHaxG5dC5qL5EAFviFIvCmiXeGACtESv8GRAUH80Fa0EYxANRrqptE19hKBNBILANwTR0kzdAD2izTQQywFIQxAe0S3tcsqxrKCZxvGCgPXKBRzsBQgA)

### Update

To get better inference on the return type the signature gets a bit more complicated but it can be done:

```js
type Cases<V extends {tag: string}> = {
    [K in V['tag']]: (v: Extract<V, {tag: K}>) => any
}
type OnlyKnownCases<C, T> = C & Record<Exclude<keyof C, T>, "Unknown case"> & Record<any, Function>

function match<V extends {tag: string}, C extends Cases<V> = Cases<V>>(value: V, cases: OnlyKnownCases<C, V['tag']>): ReturnType<C[V['tag']]> {
  return cases[value.tag](value);
}
```

Introducing the generic `C` allows the return type to be specified in terms of the parameter such that it is deferred to the call-site. Unfortunately this allows for extra cases since anything that `extends Cases<V>` is allowed. We restrict this by saying any case that is not on a valid tag (`Exclude<keyof C, T>`) must map to the string `"Unknown case"` which gives a nicer error than `never`. For completeness I've added `& Record<any, Function>` so that in the very odd event that a case function is written as `"Unknown case"` it won't bypass our restriction.

`ReturnType<C['someTag']>` gives the return type of the case function for someTag. So `ReturnType<C[V['tag']]>` will work over the union of all the cases to give the union of all the returned types from the case functions.

[Link to playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZwggPANShAHsCA7AEwSgG9g4BzALigWACcBLPCgXwD4oBeUgKCgFQA2gGkozKGiEBychWkBdBTQAUANxoBRHPTgBjYOgA0pOTREcAlN05w8IXq16hIUAPJ4ANiBF4A9gDuePBIqDAmACqcPDBQAGRQAEoQen70BCjaep4ArgQQKADWECB+AGawkewmAEQAqniF-kFQeogQNZwJyanpKHYgJgBiOXgGjH547Ly8ZaPjk1AAtnDAegAW6Jg4+ESmlDR0TCysJrHYuITEIcjo0bDtqGjs7OpwuRA0aCZtoTQe3l8gWCjxQ4UkMjkinYlhoyWAOXoeAi4AKMCEUlklEUCk4JH4UHoEARSNajyEaneOQgADo5Ao3h9LABuRwzAD07O2cCWYE80AAjM5UVAAMrrOCuLgEgA++2oUGkekY9GyEGkJl0BEYOQQNDwOSWACMIPQnAI5WQDorcDgjX4sBqoLbgIcGMw2KzeKk8HRaBLIDRxZLoDwrQrZBd7Y6TC6aNIABIQTyePxQAJpTwEACE0lYXp9CD8-JpqYoKhWa02wcgrwQAYgJnxAk5UHtwHWUDKjGTezgRMJEAAjjkVRACATlar+aoSFqdQhWNYuJwAAYAQVaKrV6cYHcJcG1uqgABI54eF6xV0YCS7o7OXUubFAN86Lm2Hc6JcBaHAQMQajPR8amvRxLBZKBWwAWk4aRNxdD8sC-VZf3-KAaiTFM0wzegs2zGppA5LlsB5PloAAJm9SY-TAPxmB-MMzEVWj6KdLAaAFEwQBocjWCgRBWmo4AC2o4taTLCtVg2FQWLwYAmwJVtJm8KBJmgX5oEYYgiRHMcCCgFQ7H095UwCcdLAJWTXQMkgsC4p8VxfTcrP4n8VDPLBTlPEgQCXUCWy5AY3A7U0blnBzYOkSDiPoeg0mzMCIOg2DnLouTXIMzioHIyxCOFVwAEk8DKU1uHleMyj8Pw8ygS0mOkI1+xqurrQauAAC8814Sl6CgdioCKkr6FZQsfyJBAck8Bjlik9YVCwbMm0qvwaAAfWfLLGvoNbn2kcinUa9qdscoQAGYFCXXggA)

Comment: Nice!

Is it possible to adjust this type so that it correctly infers the return type? Right now it seems to always evaluate to `unknown` unless you specify it explicitly.

Comment: More specifically, I'd expect the type returned by `match` to be a union of all the types returned by the case functions stored under appropriate tags.

Comment: The inference in that case is based on the usage. Since the result is fed into `console.log` it simply needs to be `any` so `R` is inferred as `any`. Assigning to `let t: string = match(point, {...})` would cause inference to unify `R` as `string`.

Comment: Right, but that requires specifying the returned type explicitly.

There are other cases like `const result = match(x, {foo: _ => 1, bar: _ => '2', baz: _ => [3]})` where the correct returned type is `1 | '2' | number[]`. It'd be convenient to be able to infer that instead of writing it explicitly.

Comment: That was keeping me up all night but I think it should be working as desired now. Thank you for the very interesting question.

Comment: Thank *you* for finding a solution, this is awesome and very useful :D

I'll add the fourth property to the original question.

Would you be interested in publishing this as a package?

Comment: Looks like even `(cases as any)` is unnecessary now!

Comment: My pleasure, I won't publish as a package but you are more than welcome to!

Comment: I'll make sure to mention/ping you if I do :)